# Why Kotlin's collect function doesn't terminate itself?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

When I download info from a DataBase the collect function doesn’t stop emission (Kotlin's collect function doesn't terminate itself.)

I have this entity class:

```
@Entity
data class ShareEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val secId: String,
    val shortName: String,
    val fullName: String = "",
    val isFavorite: Boolean
)
```

The function to get all the shares for specific by “isFavorite” in the Dao looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface DataBaseDao {
………..
@Query("SELECT * FROM ShareEntity WHERE isFavorite =:isFavorite")
fun getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean): Flow<List<ShareEntity>>
}
```

In the DataBaseDao there are many other functions that insert some data into ShareEntity entity.

For working with the Dao interface the DataBaseRepository and its implementation DataBaseRepositoryIm were made:

```
interface DataBaseRepository {
………..
fun getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean): Flow<List<ShareEntity>>
}
```

```
class DataBaseRepositoryIm(
private val dataBaseDao: DataBaseDao
) : DataBaseRepository{
………..
override fun getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean): Flow<List<ShareEntity>> {
 return dataBaseDao.getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite)
}
}
```

In my NewsScreenViewModel1 I have a function that loads all the Shares by “isFavorite”

```
@HiltViewModel
class NewsScreenViewModel1 @Inject constructor(
    private val dataBaseRepository: DataBaseRepository,
    private val repository: ApiRepository,
) : ViewModel(){

suspend fun downloadListOfSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean = true){
 val shares = dataBaseRepository.getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite).collect{ it:List<ShareEntity> ->
 println("NewsScreenVM1: allShares is with isFavorite = $isFavorite are $it")
 println("NewsScreenVM1: the size of shares is ${it.size}")
 }
 println("NewsScreenVM1: Now we are outside of the collect function")
}
}
```

In the composable NewsScreen I start the function with LauncheEffect:

```
@Composable
fun NewsScreen(
    NewsScreenViewModel1: NewsScreenViewModel1 = hiltViewModel()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        NewsScreenViewModel1.downloadListOfSharesByIsFavorite()
    }

}
```

The problem is that collect function doesn’t terminate itself or in other words it doesn’t stop. In the LogCat I see:

“NewsScreenVM1: allShares is with isFavorite = true are [ShareEntity(secId=ALRS, shortName=АЛРОСА ао, fullName=, isFavorite=true), ShareEntity(secId=AGRO, shortName=AGRO-гдр, fullName=, isFavorite=true), ShareEntity(secId=AFLT, shortName=Аэрофлот, fullName=, isFavorite=true), ShareEntity(secId=FEES, shortName=Россети, fullName=, isFavorite=true)]”

“NewsScreenVM1: the size of shares is 4”

And there is no: "NewsScreenVM1: Now we are outside of the collect function” which means the collect function hasn’t stopped its emission and is still running.

What did I do wrong? Why I can’t execute lines of the code after collecting some data from the database?

I tried to run the flow on a different coroutine scope like this:

```
fun downloadListOfSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean = true){
 viewModelScope.launch { 
val shares = dataBaseRepository.getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite).collect{ it:List<ShareEntity> -> 
println("NewsScreenVM1: allShares is with isFavorite = $isFavorite are $it")
println("NewsScreenVM1: the size of shares is ${it.size}")
}
println("NewsScreenVM1: Now we are outside of the collect function")
}
}
```

But the message, 'NewsScreenVM1: Now we are outside of the collect function,' appears right before all the calculations, which is not what I want. I want it to be the last massage.

When I use async function couple with .await() I don’t get the last message either as the flow never stops. Here is the code:

```
suspend fun downloadListOfSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite: Boolean = true) {
        val asyncValue = viewModelScope.async {
            var size = 0
            val shares = dataBaseRepository.getAllSharesByIsFavorite(isFavorite)
                .collect { it: List<ShareEntity> ->
                    println("NewsScreenVM1: allShares is with isFavorite = $isFavorite are $it")
                    println("NewsScreenVM1: the size of shares is ${it.size}")
                    size = it.size

                }
            size
        }
            println("NewsScreenVM1: Now we are outside of the collect function. The list size is ${asyncValue.await()}")
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the point of using a `Flow`. It doesn't end because it's waiting for DB updates. Every time the list changes in DB, you will get the new updated list in `collect`. By design it is not meant to end:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow

If what you want is to just query the current list once, no need for a `Flow` nor a `collect` call. Just use a `suspend` function that returns a `List`.

Comment: You said : " Just use a suspend function that returns a List." Did you talk about the Dao function?

Comment: Yes, you can define the DAO function as `suspend` and return the item directly instead of a Flow. But if you do use the flow elsewhere in your app and only need the single item in this one part of your app, the other option is to call `flow.first()` instead of collecting it.

Comment: Thanks, Joffrey! That really helps! I think the first option would be more suitable for the problem I work on!